# Left Click doesn't work at all on Mac, even after reinstallation

Tags: selection-tools

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBpYz.jpg

For some reason, I can't use my left mouse button at all, as shown in the screen capture, it only works after I restore everything to factory defaults but it doesn't stay that way after I reopen blender.

I am using MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), 2.2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB. I deleted completely and reinstalled blender twice and I am using the most recent version as of yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Alright after a long battle I managed to delete every single file related to blender on the computer and reinstalled and now it works. Considered the question solved.